# Is my onBackPressed() implementation wrong?

Tags: android, onclicklistener, back

I want to use Back button programmaticaly, when i pressed back button:

```
onback.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override   
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

i want to display previous page same as i do by Clicking Back on device. Then i do:

```
onback.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override   
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onBackPressed();

        }
    });
```

gives 'undefined type for Object' error. Then i tried:

```
onback.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onBackPressed(View v) {
            // Do something
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    });
```

No functioning. I checked several question and answers, no answer for onClick and without 'finish()' the activity. Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: JFYI, bear in mind that the default back button in Android is part of the design of the platform (as opposite as iOS), so in most cases there is no need at all to create a button like that...

Comment: why i need to use this button is not i want to replace with function of device. That is all to let my app go previous page which has user form and edit it back under button named 'Edit'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't call `super`. Just do:

```
    onback.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Do something
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });
```

Comment: this works with some changes if i use public void onClick(View v) instead yours (public void onBackPressed(View v)). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Override the super class and call the method

```
    onback.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override   
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                onBackPressed();

      }
    });


    @Override    
    public void onBackPressed()
        { 
        //custom backpressed code
        }
```

Comment: Sorry but you're wrong. He is not trying to override that method, but calling it from a custom buttom click.

Comment: then you have to create a onclicklistener and call onBackPressed() in that method ;)

Comment: And that's @Egor N answer, xD.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this ..

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
    }
```

If U need back functionality on press of button on your UI then try like this ..

```
back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                finish();
            }
        });

Button back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back);
```

Here calling finish(); in itself kills current activity and initiates previous activity... No need for over head .

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this by doing this simply

```
onback.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                 finish();

            } 


        });
```

Comment: This will kill the activity. I don't want it to happen.

Comment: back button also do the same. If you dont want to kill activity use intent flags.

Comment: Sorry but that is wrong idea. Let me explain with example: I fill up the form such as Name, Company, Phone etc. and when i click display it displays all. When i clicked back on device, goes previous page as my content is left there in the form. I can modify it or clear.

Comment: Same will happen with finish check it .